# Morse Encoding with Binary Tree in Python

Tags: python, binary-tree, morse-code

I am trying to code a program that encodes/decodes Morse Code using a binary tree. Initially my code worked by taking an input when run and successfully converted it to Morse code.

However, I am trying to make it so that the terminal command **encode('xyz')** will take the xyz string and convert to the Morse, returning the result. To do this, I have had to rejig the code, and am now running into errors. Is there something obvious I am missing?

```
class BTree: 
    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left 
        self.right = right 

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left:
                    self.left.insert(data)
                else: 
                    self.left = BTree(data) 
            elif data > self.data: 
                if self.right:
                    self.right.insert(data) 
                else:
                    self.right = BTree(data) 
        else:
            self.data = data

    def output(self): 
        if self.left:
            self.left.output() 
        print(self.data) 
        if self.right: 
            self.right.output() 

    def encode(self, msg: str):
        dotsdashes = []
        code = "".join(dotsdashes)

        for character in msg:
            self.getMorse(code, character, dotsdashes)
            morseCode = morseCode + code + " "

    def getMorse(self, node, character, code):
        if node==None:
            return False
        elif node.data == character:
            return True
        else:
            if self.getMorse(node.left,character,code) == True:
                code.insert(0,".")
                return True
            elif self.getMorse (node.right,character,code)==True:
                code.insert(0,"-")
                return True
```

My main function (won't format properly when copied and pasted as one):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = BTree("Root")
    root.left = BTree("E")
    root.right = BTree("T")
    root.left.left = BTree("I")
    root.left.right = BTree("A")
    root.right.left = BTree("N")
    root.right.right = BTree("M")
    root.left.left.left = BTree("S")
    root.left.left.right = BTree("U")
    root.left.right.left = BTree("R")
    root.left.right.right = BTree("W")
    root.right.left.left = BTree("D")
    root.right.left.right = BTree("K")
    root.right.right.left = BTree("G")
    root.right.right.right = BTree("O")
    root.left.left.left.left = BTree("H")
    root.left.left.left.right = BTree("V")
    root.left.left.right.left = BTree("F")
    root.left.left.right.right = BTree("")
    root.left.right.left.left = BTree("L")
    root.left.right.left.right = BTree("")
    root.left.right.right.left = BTree("P")
    root.left.right.right.right = BTree("J")
    root.right.left.left.left = BTree("B")
    root.right.left.left.right = BTree("X")
    root.right.left.right.left = BTree("C")
    root.right.left.right.right = BTree("Y")
    root.right.right.left.left = BTree("Z")
    root.right.right.left.right = BTree("Q")
    root.right.right.right.left = BTree("")
    root.right.right.right.right = BTree("")
```

Also wondering if populating the binary tree in the main function rather than it's own function was the right thing to do?

I'm relatively new to using binary trees so apologies for the potentially poor explanation/silly question.

EDIT: I should have included that the most recent error I am getting is: *line 41, in getMorse
elif node.data == character:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'*

Comment: Why don't you just use a dict..? `morse = {'a': '.-', 'b': '-...', etc.}` then to encode `''.join(morse[ch] for ch in 'xyz'))`

Answer (score 3):

There are these issues:

- In `morseCode = morseCode + code + " "` you reference `morseCode` on the right side of the assignment, but it was never initialised with a value. So you need to initialise it before the loop with the empty string
- In the call `self.getMorse(code, character, dotsdashes)` you pass a string `code` as first argument, but the function expects a node there. So you should pass `self` as argument instead of `code`
- `self.getMorse` returns a boolean, but in the above call you never look at this boolean. You should probably do something when that returned value is false.
- `code = "".join(dotsdashes)` is happening too soon (and only once). This should happen in the loop *after* you made the call to `self.getMorse` as only then `dotsdashes` will have been populated.
- `dotsdashes = []` should happen *each time* before you call `self.getMorse`, as otherwise it will just accumulate the new morse code adjacent to what it already had from a previous iteration.
- `encode` should return the result.

Here is a correction of that `encode` function:

```
    def encode(self, msg: str):
        morseCode = ""  # Init
        for character in msg:
            dotsdashes = []  # Moved inside the loop
            success = self.getMorse(self, character, dotsdashes) # Change first argument
            if not success:  # Deal with return value
                raise ValueError(f"Invalid character - no Morse code available for {character}")
            code = "".join(dotsdashes)  # Moved inside the loop
            morseCode = morseCode + code + " "
        return morseCode  # Return
```

Remarks:

- It seems overkill to really create a tree for this. A dictionary seems more appropriate: it requires less code and will not need to walk through a tree to find a character, which could be anywhere.
- It is not best practice to pass a list as third argument to `self.getMorse`, which it populates. Better is to make that the return value, and to return `None` if there is no Morse code available.
- The `insert` method implements a binary *search* tree, which is not what you need here. It should not be included in your class.

### Alternative tree

The tree you have created is a [*complete* binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) (even a perfect one), so you can encode that tree in a list (as is often done for [binary heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Implementation)). And since the data for each node is just a character, it could be a *string* instead of a list.

The binary representation of an index in that string could then be made to be the Morse code (where 0,1 maps to dot,dash respectively) of the character at that index. To make sure that all binary 0 are *included* in the binary representation, even when they occur before any 1, we can go for binary representations where the first 1 is ignored, and all other binary digits represent the actual Morse code.

This leads to the following code, which is still tree-based:

```
MORSE = "..ETIANMSURWDKGOHVF.L.PJBXCYZQ"

def encode_char(c):
    return bin(MORSE.index(c))[3:].replace("0", ".").replace("1", "-")

def encode(s):
    return " ".join(map(encode_char, s))

print(encode("SOS"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the informative answer and alternative tree method. I've made the changes you suggested to the encode function but am now only getting 'invalid character' (or the empty string) returned when I run?

Comment: How do you run it? Which string do you pass? Did your input string have non-capital-alphabetical characters, like spaces or punctuation or digits or lower case letters? Realise that your tree only supports 26 characters ("A".."Z"). For it to work with anything else you need to specify what should happen or extend your tree.

Comment: Good point I was using lower case, however (running with command 'tt.encode('HI')') have tried with uppercase, individual letters etc and all seem to just return the empty string

Comment: I don't see `tt` in your code.

Comment: Terminal commands 'import morse as bt', 'tt = bt.BTree()', 'tt.encode()'  (morse being the name of the .py file, BTree the name of the class)

Comment: But that is not the code you have provided in the question. It seems `tt` is just an empty tree. I used the code in your question and only replaced `encode` with my version, and it works. As can be seen on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma717969425459839)

Comment: Oh, this is the way I was shown to run the code in the terminal, and has worked so far for tt.insert() and tt.output() etc. when I was using those functions - how do I go about being able to run the program and use the 'encode('XYZ')' command from the terminal (using VSCode)?

Comment: Comments are not really intended for follow up questions. It will work fine via the terminal *if you build the tree* and explicitly *print* the resulting string (see the `print` in the code I linked to). Apparently you are not executing the code in the `main` section or not printing the result. If you have trouble getting that to work, please ask a new question providing all the details to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Anyway, for executing the main part (which builds the tree): put that in a function, and call that function, so at least you build the tree, and let it *return* the tree it builds. That should become your `tt` variable. And so on... See [updated repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma717969425459839bis)